# find files under directory and cp to the target but only keep subdirectory parents structure

Tags: linux, find

Here is my task
find `.stats` file under directory `*/*long*/stats` and excute `cp` files to the target directory but keep only parent directory of `/*long*/stats` not `*/*long*/stats`
for example:
cp foo/*long*/stats/file.stats to target/*long*/stats/file.stats

I tried

```
find */*long*/stats -name '*.stats' -exec cp --parents \{} target/ \;
```

It copy `*/*long*/stats` to the target

I tried

```
find */*long*/stats -name '*.stats' -exec cp --parents -maxdepth 2 \{} target/ \;
```

not working too.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I suspect I misunderstood the question in my answer. Do you mean you want to copy `foo/xlongy/stats/a/b/c/file.stats` to `target/a/b/c/file.stats` or `target/xlongy/stats/a/b/c/files.stats` or anything else?

Comment: cp foo/xlongy/stats/a/b/c/file.stats to target/a/b/c/file.stats. thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you'd like to  copy `foo/XlongY/stats/a/b/c/file.stats` to `target/a/b/c/file.stats` for instance, you could do (with `bash` or `zsh`, and assuming GNU `find`/`cp`):

```
target=$PWD/target
find ./*/*long*/stats -name '*.stats' -type f -printf '%H\0%P\0' |
  while
    IFS= read -rd '' dir &&
      IFS= read -rd '' file
  do
    (cd "$dir" && exec cp --parents -- "$file" "$target/")
  done
```

or

```
target=$PWD/target
for dir in ./*/*long*/stats/; do
  (
    cd "$dir" &&
     exec find . -name '*.stats' -type f -exec cp --parents -t "$target" {} +
  )
done
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/files # makes mkdir and cp builtin to speed things up
mkcp() { mkdir -p -- "$2:h" && cp -- "$@"; }
zmv -P mkcp '*/*long*/stats/(**/)(*.stats)(#qD.)' 'target/$1$2'
```

That one would guard against file name clashes but not copy the directory metadata.

Or you could use `pax` (assuming yours supports `-0`)

```
find ./*/*long*/stats -name '*.stats' -type f -print0 |
  pax -0 -rwpe -'s|^\./[^/]*/[^/]*/stats/||' target/
```

Comment: thank you stephane! I tried the first and second script, It copies .stats file to target/.stats without any parents structure. Hope my updates above help clarify my problem.

Comment: @zenoZeng, to add clarifications to your question (like with examples of input and expected output), you would click the [edit](/posts/593136/edit) link under your question. The only *update* from you I can see is the new *comment* on your answer which would seem to indicate that my answer does what you want.